# What is the result of $\delta'*H$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

What is the result of $\delta'*H$ where $\delta$ is the  Dirac delta and $H$ is the Heaviside function i.e., $H(t)=1$ if $t\geq1$ and vanishes everywhere else?

Note that,  $\delta'$ is the distribution derivation of $\delta$.

Comment: When defined, $F' * G = F * G'$.

Comment: Nice formula! Based on it $\delta=\delta'*H$. Could you please write a little more  about the formiula?

Comment: For test functions you can do it by writing out the definition of convolution and integrating by parts. For distributions combine with the definition of distributional derivative.

Comment: Even $F' * G = (F * G)' = F * G'.$

Comment: The usual [Heaviside Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) is defined differently ($H(t)=[t\ge0]$ using [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)). Did you really mean the one in the question?

Comment: @robjohn, Yes, I do.

Comment: Ok. Then $H'(x)=\delta(x-1)$.